# Vnstat shows 500MB daily of RX transfer on non operational server

Tags: networking, linux-networking, centos7, local-area-network

I'm running Centos7 on a VPS with **apache** and a **1KB php application** deployed that i use **for tests**, the logs don't have any entries other than my own and a couple of bots.

I have **vnstat** for tracking traffic and it used to be **20MB daily of RX**, i'm always on ssh.

**After** i installed **LetsEncrypt ssl** with certbot it jumped to Nearly **500MB daily of RX** traffic. TX is at 90mb.

I installed **nethogs** to track traffic on eth0 by application but the higher rx rate comes from ssh and it's only a couple of MB/S after hours.

**Update:** 
 Tcpdump and tshark output shows dozens of ARP requests per second:

```
Broadcast ARP 60 Who has X.X.X.X? Tell X.X.X.X
```

**Update2:**
ARP Packets detailed format:

```
TIME `MyMAC` (oui Unknown) > `UnknownMAC` (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x800), length 87: vps.xxxcloud.com > resolver.dns.xxxx.com PTR someIP.in-addr.arpa (45)
```

**Update3:**
I'm ignoring ARP packets based on [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/266547/how-to-find-the-process-which-causes-the-arp-request). vnstat estimated RX transfer for the month is 10.21GB on a testing environment, still a mystery for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tcpdump to capture and after analyze that capture with wireshark.
With wireshark analytics tab can show you the top 10 of bandwidth consumers

Comment: i updated the post with more details.

Comment: can you please check if the source mac address of those packages is your VM's mac.

Comment: yes, it looks like it is, here's the format:
time <myMac> (oui Unknown) > <UnknownMac>, ethertype IPv4 (0x800), length 87: vps.xxxcloud.com > resolver.dns.xxxx.com PTR weirdIP.in-addr.arpa (45)

Comment: ok ok , do you know the ip your server is asking for? if you don't use that ip address your server is asking for, you can drop those packages using `arptables`, i just wrote a little how to use arptables http://blog.infratic.com/2017/02/avoid-arp-requests-rhelcentossl/

Comment: There are multiple ips, they are variations of my vps public ip. It's always vps.xxxcloud.xxx.com > resolver.dns.xxxx.com.
I'm going to contact the vps support, thanks for the help.